# Writing two lists with different length as columns to a data file

Tags: python, list

I am considering the two list:
    `a = [2, 4, 7]`
    `b = [6, 9, 10, 90, 80]`

I want to write these lists to a data file to show the elements of list 'a' in one column and of 'b' in the second column taking into consideration that a and b are not the same length.

Comment: I do not understand what do you actually want.

Comment: Instead of using columns of fixed length, separate the fields with a delimiter, like a comma. When reading the file, separate each row by the delimiter (the comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small variation from @eumiro

```
with open("test.txt","w") as fin:
    #izip_longest create consecutive tuples of elements from the list of iterables
    #where if any of the iterable's length is less than the longest length of the
    #iterable, fillvalue is taken as default
    #If you need formatted output, you can use str.format
    #The format specifier here used specifies the length of each column
    #to be five and '^' indicates that the values would be center alligned
    for e in izip_longest(a,b,fillvalue=''):
         print >>fin,"{:^5} {:^5}".format(*e)
         #if you are using Python 3.x
         #fin.write("{:^5} {:^5}\n".format(*e))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import itertools as it
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csvw = csv.writer(f)
    for aa, bb in it.izip_longest(a, b):
        csvw.writerow(aa, bb)
```

or a shorter version inspired by @katriealex:

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(it.izip_longest(a, b))
```

Comment: `writerow` takes a single argument (the row) and `csvw.writerows` is even neater =)

Comment: your script give me column separated by commas and this is not what I need